# Try except block python varies result

Tags: python, try-except

I am reading some .json files. Some of the files are empty. So I am using `try-except` block to read.
If it is empty then except condition will be executed. My code snippet looks like this:

```
exec = True
for jsonidx, jsonpath in enumerate(jsonList):
    print("\n")
    print(">>> Reading {} of {} json file: {}".format(jsonidx, len(jsonList), os.path.basename(jsonpath)))
    try:
        with open(jsonpath, "r") as read_file:
            jsondata = json.load(read_file)
        outPath = r'{}'.format(outPath)
        dicomPath = os.path.join(outPath, 'dicoms')
        nrrdPath = os.path.join(outPath, 'nrrds')
        if exec: # if you want to execute the move
            if not os.path.isdir(outPath):  # if the outPath directory doesn't exist.
                 os.mkdir(outPath)
                 os.mkdir(dicomPath)
                 os.mkdir(nrrdPath)
        thisJsonDcm = []
        for widx, jw in enumerate(jsondata['workItemList']):
            # print('\n')
            print('-------------------- Extracting workitem #{} --------------------'.format(widx))
            seriesName = jw['imageSeriesSet'][0]['seriesLocalFolderName']   # this is dicom folder whole path
            thisJsonDcm.append(seriesName)
   except:
        print("Json empty")
```

The code ran perfectly at the first couple of times or so, where it iterates the second `for` loop with `jsondata["workItemList"]`.
But when I run later again, the second `for` loop doesn't iterate and all the iterations show the print statement inside except `json empty`.

Does `try-except` block have any state or specific behavior?? Do I need to delete or refresh something after running the first time to repeat again?

Comment: That `try` block is waaaay too big.  Any number of errors could be lurking in there, completely unrelated to an empty json file.

Comment: `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError` should handle the only json read errors? suggested by @Tikhon
Yeah, the `try` block is 'too big' I agree. Are there smarter ways to deal with this? I need to read the json file and perform some jobs.

Comment: Generally you want to make `try` blocks as small as possible.  Make it so the block covers _only_ the `with open` and `json.load()` lines.

Comment: Also, where does `outPath` come from?  Is it defined above this code?

Comment: The `outPath` is just a directory where I save the results. So to make the `try` block smaller. How do I use `jsondata` if 1. try doesn't give error. 2. try gives error?

Comment: If the try gives an error, then jsondata won't exist.  So you would probably want to skip to the next loop iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError` exception.

It looks like this:

```py
try:
    pass
    """Some stuff with json..."""
except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError:
    print("Json empty")
```

More about in [Json Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#exceptions)

Or you can handle error only when loading json

```py
exec = True
for jsonidx, jsonpath in enumerate(jsonList):
    print("\n")
    print(">>> Reading {} of {} json file: {}".format(jsonidx, len(jsonList), os.path.basename(jsonpath)))
    with open(jsonpath, "r") as read_file:
        try:
            jsondata = json.load(read_file)
        except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError:
            print("Json empty")
            continue
    outPath = r'{}'.format(outPath)
    dicomPath = os.path.join(outPath, 'dicoms')
    nrrdPath = os.path.join(outPath, 'nrrds')
    if exec: # if you want to execute the move
         if not os.path.isdir(outPath):  # if the outPath directory doesn't exist.
             os.mkdir(outPath)
             os.mkdir(dicomPath)
             os.mkdir(nrrdPath)
    thisJsonDcm = []
    for widx, jw in enumerate(jsondata['workItemList']):
        # print('\n')
        print('-------------------- Extracting workitem #{} --------------------'.format(widx))
        seriesName = jw['imageSeriesSet'][0]['seriesLocalFolderName']   # this is dicom folder whole path
        thisJsonDcm.append(seriesName)
```

You can read more about try/except in [Python Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html)

Comment: In the second case, where does the for statement come? the chunk where I do stuff with the json file.

Comment: Yes, `pass` is not required. This solution will handle only errors when file is empty or json is not valid in file, all other errors will raise normally. If you want to check only if file is empty, you can read it it first and compare with `''` (`if f.read().strip() == '':`)

Comment: I just updated second solution with full code

Comment: I get error: `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'jsondata' referenced before assignment` at line `for widx, jw in enumerate(jsondata['workItemList']):` when an empty json comes in the outer `for` loop.

Comment: Yes, you need to go to next iteration if file is empty: just place `continue` after `print("Json empty")`

Comment: Hello, @Tikhon this worked perfectly. Thanks.